# Azure App Registration is used for Authorization when securing a Python Http trigger Function App

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, authorization

I have a requirement where I will create a azure Http trigger using python function app.

For this function app I need to provide Authorization by using client Id or client Secret. Where the http link has to approved only with the client secret

I couldn't found any reference in python.

If any one has done this method can u show ur code for reference or guide me to solve this

Comment: You need to register your app in Azure AD under Azure Active Directory > App Registrations and then on the Overview tab you will see client Id assigned to your app. Then you need to add a secret on the same tab.

Comment: Hi Delta George,   I don't have access to Azure AD. I need to give a code structure  using python and they will do the app registration and will replace the Client id. I need a reference of python code structure how to implement. If you have the code can you share here

Answer (score 0):

**Here's Microsoft documentation that you can use to get an idea of how to [implement Azure AD Authentication into your Python Function App via code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate).**

It includes other authentication methods also like Authentication with `service principals`, `user credentials`, `AzureCliCredential` or `Managed Identity` and `DefaultAzureCredential`.

Instead of facing difficulties in accessing the Client Id or Secret from Azure AD if you do not have access to it, you can store them in **Azure Key Vault** and access through Python Code in the same Azure Function App:

```
import os from azure.identity 
import DefaultAzureCredential from azure.keyvault.secrets 
import SecretClient

vault_url = os.environ["KEY_VAULT_URL"]
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=vault_url, credential=credential)

retrieved_secret = secret_client.get_secret("secret-name-01")
```

**And this  [Microsoft Blog Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-python-webapi-azurefunctions/ms-identity-python-webapi-azurefunctions/) presents you to register the Azure Python Function App with Azure AD using Azure CLI Commands and access the HTTP Trigger URL secured with the **Client Id**.**

Comment: Hi thanks, So can we redirect the Http function app to Microsoft login page after successful credentials it has to redirect to Http function app link.